How do you rename a module using nwidart package?
I'm using the nwidart/laravel-modules packages to setup modular structure for my Laravel project, and I have a module named Company that I want to rename into Facility but I'm not exactly sure about the required steps, and the documentation doesn't mention the required steps to do this.

Assuming you have a module called Company that you want to rename into Facility, here's what you need to do:

Change the name of the folder that contains the module files

Rename the module inside the modules_statuses.json file, for example, change:


{
    "Company": true
}

Into:
{
    "Facility": true
}


Make sure to replace the namespace definition in all your classes inside the module, as well as the any place in your code where a class is being used from the renamed module, for example, change:

use Modules\Company\Models\Company;

Into:
use Modules\Facility\Models\Company;

Some suggested places to make those changes are the models classes, controllers classes, repositories classes, services classes, database seeders, and migration files. Respectable IDEs such as PHPStorm has an awesome refactoring feature that automatically updates the namespace definition in all classes.

Inside the RouteServiceProvider class of your module, make sure to update the calls for your route files to be loaded from the correct path, for example, change:

protected function mapApiRoutes(): void
    {
        Route::middleware('api')->prefix('api')->name('api.')->group(module_path('Company', '/routes/api.php'));
    }

Into:
protected function mapApiRoutes(): void
    {
        Route::middleware('api')->prefix('api')->name('api.')->group(module_path('Facility', '/routes/api.php'));
    }


Inside the main module service provider class, make sure to update the $moduleName and the $moduleNameLower attributes:

protected string $moduleName = 'Facility';
protected string $moduleNameLower = 'facility';


Inside the config.php file of your module, update the name key to reflect the new name of the module:

return [
    'name' => 'Facility',
];


Inside the composer.json file of your module (the one inside your module directory, and not the one in the project root directory), make sure to update the used namespace, for example change:

{
    "name": "nwidart/company",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nicolas Widart",
            "email": "n.widart@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [],
            "aliases": {

            }
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Modules\\Company\\": "app/",
            "Modules\\Company\\Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Modules\\Company\\Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Modules\\Company\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}

Into:
{
    "name": "nwidart/facility",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nicolas Widart",
            "email": "n.widart@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [],
            "aliases": {

            }
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Modules\\Facility\\": "app/",
            "Modules\\Facility\\Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Modules\\Facility\\Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Modules\\Facility\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}



Inside the module.json file of your module, also make sure to update the name of the module and the namespace for the module service provider, for example change:

{
    "name": "Company",
    "alias": "company",
    "description": "",
    "keywords": [],
    "priority": 0,
    "providers": [
        "Modules\\Company\\Providers\\CompanyServiceProvider"
    ],
    "files": []
}

Into:
{
    "name": "Facility",
    "alias": "facility",
    "description": "",
    "keywords": [],
    "priority": 0,
    "providers": [
        "Modules\\Facility\\Providers\\CompanyServiceProvider"
    ],
    "files": []
}


Run php artisan optimize:clear command to clear all configured cache that may be problematic.
Run composer dump-autoload to recreate the autoloader, this is very important and without it you will see many errors of classes being loaded using the incorrect namespace.

Few additional checks you may need to consider

If you're using polymorphic relationships, or if you're using packages that may implicitly using polymorphic relationships in their work (e.g. zoha/laravel-meta, spatie/laravel-medialibrary), you will need to go to the database and update model_type field to point to the correct namespace, this is necessary to avoid problems with existing data. You may safely ignore this if you're using a morphMap() to giving a custom names to the values inside the model_type field.

